# Testing consistency with Selenium scraping

Tags: python, datetime, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This script scrapes data from a website with upcoming sports games into a dictionary ([www.oddsportal.com](http://www.oddsportal.com)). Takes under 2.5 mins.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import time

upcoming = ['http://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/usa/wnba/']
nextgames = []

def rescrape(urls, cs):

    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:/phantomjs.exe') 
    driver.get('http://www.oddsportal.com/set-timezone/15/')
    # The above link sets the timezone. I believe problem lies here, explicit wait?    
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)

    for url in urls:        
        for i in range(2): 
            #This is to run the the scrape twice within function. It scrapes the same way both times        
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)            
            driver.get(url)
            # this is to ensure the table with games has appeared            
            try:     
                wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#tournamentTable tr.odd")))
            except TimeoutException:
                continue
            # below is the script to get details from each game            
            for match in driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table#tournamentTable").find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')[3:]:
                try:
                    home, away = match.find_element_by_class_name("table-participant").text.split(" - ")
                except:
                    continue

                date = match.find_element_by_xpath(".//preceding::th[contains(@class, 'first2')][1]").text
                kickoff = match.find_element_by_class_name("table-time").text
                # following deals with exceptions to a recognized date format
                if "oday" in date:
                    date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d %b %Y")
                    event = "Not specified"

                elif "omorrow" in date:
                    date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
                    date = date.strftime("%d %b %Y")                

                elif "esterday" in date:
                    date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
                    date = date.strftime("%d %b %Y")                            
                elif " - " in date:
                    date, event = date.split(" - ", 1)                    


                nextgames.append({
                    "current time": time.ctime(),                
                    "home": home.strip(),
                    "away": away.strip(),
                    "date": date,
                    "time": kickoff.strip()})

                time.sleep(3)
                print len(nextgames)

        print len(nextgames)
    driver.close()
    df = pd.DataFrame(nextgames)
    df.to_csv(cs, encoding='utf-8')
    return df

for i in range(3):
    rescrape(upcoming, 'trial' + str(i) + '.csv')
```

What's wrong with it is that setting timezone `driver.get('http://www.oddsportal.com/set-timezone/15/')` doesn't always work. It reverts to default timezone of GMT about 20% of the time it scrapes. This output shows the wrong date & time on the third round, after getting things right first 2 times. Notice how last range(2) loop gets both times wrong but only second date is wrong - means it can change timezone in either loop:

`pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 10)`

```
    Unnamed: 0       away current time       date       home   time
0           0   Washin...  Wed Ju...     8-Jun-16  Dallas...  20:30
1           1   San An...  Wed Ju...     9-Jun-16  Phoeni...  22:00
2           2   Washin...  Wed Ju...     8-Jun-16  Dallas...  20:30
3           3   San An...  Wed Ju...     9-Jun-16  Phoeni...  22:00
4           4   Washin...  Wed Ju...     8-Jun-16  Dallas...  20:30
5           5   San An...  Wed Ju...     9-Jun-16  Phoeni...  22:00
6           6   Washin...  Wed Ju...     8-Jun-16  Dallas...  20:30
7           7   San An...  Wed Ju...     9-Jun-16  Phoeni...  22:00
8           8   Phoeni...  Wed Ju...     8-Jun-16  Minnes...   0:00
9           9   New Yo...  Wed Ju...     8-Jun-16  Los An...   2:00
10         10   Washin...  Wed Ju...     9-Jun-16  Dallas...   0:30
11         11   San An...  Wed Ju...    10-Jun-16  Phoeni...   2:00
```

So how do I ensure the timezone `.get` works every time? Currently I have an implicit wait and have tried explicit waits to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the website creates a cookie for the user timezone, you can exploit that by adding it yourself

```
driver.add_cookie({'name': 'op_user_time_zone', 'value': '-4'})
```

That should do the trick

In case it doesn't work edit the current code to what you tried, also check the [docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html?highlight=cookie#cookies) to make sure you're implementing it correctly.